# Azure APIM Backup throwing error "Invalid parameter: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.Parameter name: backupContainerName"

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-api-management, azure-runbook

I am using the Azure automation runbook to back up APIM on the same region using "user assigned Managed Identities". Have given the role assignment "Storage Account Contributor" to the user assigned managed identity. Also whitelisted IP address of APIM control panel IP i.e "20.44.72.3" for east us 2. Doing all this still i get the error as

```
Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameters",
    "message": "Invalid parameter: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\r\nParameter name: backupContainerName (value: [apimbackup])",
    "details": null,
    "innerError": null
  }
}
```

PowerShel Script:

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId XXXX-e9f9-XXXX-ad22-95f821a2c9bc).context

# set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "rg-nau2d-XXXX-01" -StorageAccountName "stornau2dXXXXXX")[0].Value
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "stornau2dXXXXXX" -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

$storageKey
$StorageContext
$resourceGroupName="rg-nau2d-XXXX-01";
$apiManagementName="apim-01";
$containerName="apimbackup";
$backupName= $apiManagementName +"blob1";
$clientId = "XXXX-e9f9-XXXX-ad22-95f821a2c9bc"
Backup-AzApiManagement -Debug -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $apiManagementName -StorageContext $storageContext -TargetContainerName $containerName -TargetBlobName $backupName -AccessType "UserAssignedManagedIdentity" -IdentityClientId  $clientId -PassThru
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think you need to assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to it. The `Storage Account Contributor` contains no data plane actions privileges. I think APIM backups need to be stored as blobs and in that case it needs access to the blob actions which the above role will provide.

Comment: No its throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please note that the storage account that you have to back up to
   can  be in any Azure region except in the region where the API Management
   service is  located i.e.; except the same region.

- *For example*: If at all the APIM service is in West US, then the Storage account must or can be
  in    West US 2 and have  to open the API Management control plane
  IP of    West US in the firewall beacause  ***the requests to Azure
  Storage    are not SNATed to a public IP from (compute )***
  i.e. ; Azure API    Management control plane here ,***in the same
  Azure region***. Public    IP address can or will be SNATed to
  Cross-region storage requests.

2. And as you are using user assigned identity,  please make sure  that
   **identity is given or assigned  the role of   *`Storage Blob Data Contributor`*** from the  [***Azure portal***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-portal) , which has  scope
   to the storage account that you are using for  the APIM backup
   /restore.After that save changes and refresh the portal and try again.

> Note:
>
> - Backup is not possible in Consumption but is available in the Premium, Standard, Basic, and Developer tiers of API Management.
> - Also make sure CORS is not enabled to the target blob storage account

3. Also check if [backup-contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#backup-contributor) role is required in your case
4. Disable AzContextAutosave which makes sure to not to inherit  AzContext in your runbook before creating azcontext when using [backup-azapimanagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/backup-azapimanagement?view=azps-8.0.0)

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount .....).context
```

While creating the blob container to store backup , give it a **blob permission**

```
New-AzStorageContainer -Name "<apim name>" -Context $storageAccount.Context -Permission blob
```

Please check the below references to get in detail information about the same.

If the issue seems to be same , try to raise a support request for the same from support+troubleshooting blade from the azure portal.

**References:**

1. [Implement disaster recovery using backup and restore in API
   Management - Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore)
2. [Backup and Restore in Azure API Management | Azure Blog
   (svenmalvik.com)](https://www.svenmalvik.com/azure-apim-backup-restore/)

Comment: Actually we see that if storage account is in same region and have firewall enabled then it will not work even if we add control panel region public IP. Because APIM control panel cluster will use azure back bone network to talk to storage account and it uses private IP address and cluster  CIDR also changes frequently.                                                      
Solution 1) Allow all networks to storage account if its in same region as APIM 2) Place the storage account in different region and add control panel IP address to firewall